# How can I create a new temp table for each day given in a range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I need to create a temp table based on days given in example,

I need temp tables for `2015-06-08` to `2015-06-29`, I am going to create 22 temp tables, each having their own data according to date.

My query would select data into these temp tables in a loop and the only thing that needs to change is the date.

Comment: The English is OK. The idea is strange. Why would you want to  denormalize your data ? Size ?

Comment: So what part of this do you not know how to do?   Can you make your question more specific?   Do you know how to make a temp table?   Do you know how to do a loop?

Comment: This seems like a really bad design to me. You really don't need 22 temp tables, you just need a column for the date. And doing inserts in a loop is going to kill your performance.

Comment: Lol, thanks. I need to create journal entries that needs to be posted to an accounting program. Each days journals need to be separate. This is why I need a temp table for each day. Or any other suggestions? I've already got the code to select the journals. I just need the specifics for the loop as well as the variable in the temp table ( I think? ).

Comment: Because then the data needs to be split for the end user, which means data integrity is compromised.

Comment: temp tables are something what you use internally in your program. you don't provide anything to any enduser.

Comment: But I can select from a temp table and save to a document which can be sent to an end user. Any other suggestions then?

Comment: why not create one table with dates, ranging from  `2015-06-08` to `2015-06-29` and then populate that table with entries for each date ?

Comment: You don't need to split this data out into their own tables. You just need to select the data you want from your existing table as you need it. Making a copy of the data in a temp table is just wasting effort. The real problem here is that we can't help because you haven't provided any information yet. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone here is suggesting you that you do not need a table for each date but a row in a table for each date, Also you don't necessarily need to store the results into a temp table.

You can write a query which produces this date range and join your existing query with the result of date range query.

Storing results of a query is good for humans to visually see the data but sql server doesn't need data in a temp table to proceed with data processing, if you have a query which you know will produce a specific result set, you can join another table with that result set, you don't see the result set at runtime but sql server gets that result set at runtime and joins it with your table.

Now hopefully if I have convinced you that you do not need a temp table for each date lets talk about the solution.

All you need is a query which produces a result set with dates ranging `2015-06-08` to `2015-06-29` for this you can do the following:

```
DECLARE @From DATE = '2015-06-08' 
DECLARE @To   DATE = '2015-06-29'

SELECT Dates 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT TOP  (DATEDIFF(DAY,@From , @To))
      DATEADD(DAY , 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
                ,@To) AS Dates
   FROM master..spt_values
  )Dates_Table
```

The above query will produce a result set with dates, now you can join another table with this result set to get the final result you need.

Answer (score 0):

Great, but you need to change `@To` to `@From` in the DATEADD function to start from the first date. Also, one day of difference should be considered.

So I changed the code like this:

```sql
DECLARE @From DATE = '2015-06-08' 
DECLARE @To   DATE = '2015-06-29'

SELECT Dates 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT TOP  (DATEDIFF(DAY,@From , @To)+1)
      DATEADD(DAY , 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1
                ,@From) AS Dates
   FROM master..spt_values
  )Dates_Table
```